# How could I eliminate more than one row from array in an Julia?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, julia

```
function prealloc()
    situation=zeros(Int64,3^5,5);
    i=1;
    for north=0:2, south=0:2, east=0:2, west=0:2, current=0:2
        situation[i,:]=[north, south, east, west, current]
        i+=1
    end
    situation
end
prealloc()
```

How could I eliminate more than one row from array in Julia?

Comment: On what basis? By indexing? Be more specific.

Comment: this a huge array (3^5,5) i want to eliminate rows which =[2,2,2,2,2] and [2,2,2,2,1] and [2,2,2,2,0] ,because it's huge size i cant know the index of them

Comment: I already tried to do this function 
function delrow(array,row)
    return vcat(array[1:row-1,:],array[row+1:end,:])
end    but i can't know to eliminate more than row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either logical or integer indexing. For example,

```
function eliminate_matching_rows(A, pattern)
    keep = [A[i,:] != pattern for i = 1:size(A,1)]
    A[keep, :]
end
```

would eliminate all of the rows in `A` that match `pattern`.